# How to modify size of point data in 'select by location'?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes, select-by-location

In ArcGIS (10), when selecting by location, how can one change the size of the bright blue dot that highlights your selected point data? My actual dots are tiny (from symbology) but after performing 'select by location' the selected dots take up 1/4 of the screen each. I need them to remain their original size, just a different color.

Comment: I tried and do not seem to replicate this scenario.Please try some settings in  Selction>Selection Options menu item.

Comment: Ok, thought I fixed it for a moment but now the highlighted points are huge again...  Went to Selection -> Selection Options -> and unchecked 'Scale selection symbols when a reference scale is set.' I give up! I will just have to save selection as a new layer and then manipulate the symbology. I want to see the selected and non-selected together though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol (colour, size, etc) with which selected points are highlighted can be set on a per layer basis using the Selection tab of your layer's Properties.

[image]

The behaviour you are observing where selection points become very large is probably due to you having set a Reference Scale on your data frame, and then ticking `Scale selection symbols when a reference scale is set` on `Selection | Selection Options` so I recommend clearing both of those settings as your first experiment to get the precise software behaviour that you desire.

Comment: Thank you! I went into 'Selection' and that seems to be working. I had no idea I even set a Reference Scale (and no idea how I did that).